# Questions about JavaScript and a vertical, multi-level navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to make a vertical, multi-level navigation bar using only CSS and WITHOUT using JavaScript?

Like the one in here:

http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/slidedown-menu2/slidedown-menu2.html#

I am trying to avoid using JavaScript because browsers today has an option that can disable JavaScript codes. I don't want my webpages to be broken because of that settings. Should I even be thinking about this? Or should I just use JavaScript anyway?

I was hoping on using only CSS for this, though I'm not sure if CSS is enough for this.

**EDIT:** By the way, is there a CSS selector when you click an `<a>` tag? Something like 'a:click'. I only know a:hover.

Comment: You can use CSS to make multilevel menus in any direction/method, but without JS, you can't do any fancy effects like sliding.

Comment: The features that enable some of the stuff in CSS3 you will want to use aren't fully present in legacy browsers such as IE6/7/8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to have any sort of animation like that example, unless you use CSS3 animations, in which case you will have LESS support than if you used JavaScript.

If it were me, I would just use JavaScript to do it. If the user has it turned off, they will still receive the menu, just not the animation (if you code it correctly).

Comment: Does this mean that JavaScript is (or should be) used mostly for small animations only?

Comment: JavaScript can be used for much more than just animation. With that said, it can be used for small animations like this. The question to ask yourself is: Does this menu need the animation to function?

Comment: Not necessarily, though I would want to. :) 
Personally, I think that if the sample menu on the link above doesn't have animation, wouldn't that be difficult (even annoying) to use? 
I mean, the submenu shows up on 'a:hover'. If there is an alternative for that, like some sort of 'a:click'

Comment: That's the question you should be asking - is the user experience going to suffer if I don't add this? Also, as some food for thought, Yahoo has statistics that show in the US, 2% of their visitors have JS turned off, and its around 1% for outside the US. How much is 1 or 2% of your visitors going to be?

Comment: I actually don't think that 'normal' users disable their JavaScript. I just don't want any holes on my webpages. :)

Comment: Sorry to say, but you're going to be neglecting someone, at some point when making sites. Have you accounted for users that are on dialup, using something like IE 5 with images turned off? You have the right mindset in trying to accommodate for all users, but it's slightly unrealistic that all users will get the exact same experience.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4885/discussion-between-motoxer4533-and-gerald-torres)

Answer (score 2):

There are some examples here of what you can do with CSS:

http://www.cssmenus.co.uk/dropdown.html

Answer (score 2):

CSS is mainly for styling your webpages, while JavaScript is mainly for giving them different behaviors and interactivity.

That said, CSS3 is doing a lot to [change](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/) [that](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/). But, if you want a web page with any kind of Cross- browser support currently, that's not really an option.

Like you have said, users have the option of disabling JavaScript, which is a good thing for security. This, however, means that you should always try to make any JavaScript *supplementary* to your page, so there is still some functionality even if JavaScript is disabled.

If you want any interesting effects in your menu, you will need some mix of CSS and JavaScript, and if you define and apply your styles within your CSS documents and not from within your JavaScript, you will still sustain some level of usability